# Remove first character of data output

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Morning I need to drop NULL values and the first character of data output from a character field with the following values: NULL, A12345, A123456, A123456789, bytes between 6 - 10.

Is there a way to combine isnull and right(len concurrently? This the preferred method, given some additional data compilation that needs to occur downstream where the mycolumn - 1 will be used as a primary key.

Tried multiple variation on this without success, used string as well and that produced a syntax error

```
select isnull(right([my column],''len[my column]-1)  [my column]
```

This will remove null values

```
[my column] = isnull([my column],'')
```

But this does not remove the 1st character

```
right([my column], len([my column]-1) [my column]
```

Comment: What is your input/expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be something like this :

```
SELECT ISNULL(RIGHT([Value], LEN([Value])-1), ' ') AS NewValue FROM MyTable
```

You can check the execution from here :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b06c4/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
 CREATE TABLE MyTable
            (ID int,
            Value varchar(max),
            )

INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Value)VALUES(1,NULL)      
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Value)VALUES(2,'A12345')      
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Value)VALUES(3,'A123456')      
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Value)VALUES(4,'A123456789')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select ISNULL(right([Value], len([Value])-1), ' ') [Value] from MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b06c4/3/0)**:

```
|     Value |
|-----------|
|           |
|     12345 |
|    123456 |
| 123456789 |
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Fiddle, you can change the RUN SQL dropdown to Markdown output. This generates output which you can copy and paste in SO with all the right formatting to show your table setup and results

Comment: TY Steve was able to build this into my temp table and drop the character and null values

Answer (score 3):

wrong parenthesis problem, this should work.

```
right([my column], len([my column])-1) [my column]
```

and also you can use `STUFF` function

```
STUFF([my column], 1,1,'') [my column]
```

Comment: I would suggest using the STUFF as posted here. It is less effort to type, simpler and clearer, at least to me.

Comment: TY Sean I tried stuff post my original post using same sytntax as you posted and that did not drop

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
right([my column], len([my column])-1) [my column]
```

`-1` position is wrong.